# Use Regular Expression extractor to extract values from url in jmeter

Tags: regex, performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Hi Im trying to extract the first 4 values from a dtnamic url in my jmeter tests:

> https://odds-stage.sport.com/api/v1/markets?fixtureId=**1047571**%2C**1081782**%2C**1081783**%2C**1081784**%2C1081785%2C1081786%2C1081787%2C1081788%2C1081789%2C1081973%2C1081974%2C1081975%2C1081976%2C1081978%2C1081979%2C1087557%2C2030874%2C2030967%2C2031744&market=1X2

Im basically trying to extract the first four id's that appear after the url query, (they are marked in bold), i cant seem to find a way to remove %2C from between each ID,  Ive used the exteracotr before but only the JSON extractor

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution but it should do the job:

Use following Regex: `([\d+]{7})%2C([\d+]{7})%2C([\d+]{7})%2C([\d+]{7})`

[This is how my RegEx Extractor looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsWQQ.png)

You can then access the matches by using `${__groovy(vars.get("numbers_g1"))}` (if you named the created variable "numbers") [like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceWVA.png).

Unfortunately I cannot embed the images due to my lack of reputation! ;)